# ps command not showing full name of thread

Tags: ps

When I have run ps command as below on a linux machine

```
ps c -wo %cpu,%mem,cmd:20 -L -p 137985 

 %CPU %MEM CMD
 0.0  4.5 java
 0.0  4.5 java
 0.7  4.5 GC Thread#0
 0.0  4.5 G1 Main Marker
 0.0  4.5 G1 Conc#0
 0.2  4.5 G1 Refine#0
 0.1  4.5 G1 Young RemSet
 0.5  4.5 VM Thread
 0.0  4.5 Reference Handl
 0.0  4.5 Finalizer
 0.0  4.5 Signal Dispatch
 0.4  4.5 C2 CompilerT
```

I am not able to get the complete name of the thread. Is there any option I am missing?

Comment: Thread names like process names are limited to 15 bytes, that's a limitation in the Linux kernel, not `ps`.